# How to zoom to specific lat/long point in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Does QGIS have the ability to Zoom to a specific lat/long point upon the user entering one.  I can see it shows the coordinates in the bottom task bar but I'm not seeing a way to manually enter lat/long point and zoom to it.  Possibly even harder, I would like to zoom to specific lat/long point even though I'm in a UTM projection.

Comment: Without looking at it: There is a zoom to point plugin and the place finder plugin. Both can zoom you to certain point in the map

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just type into the "display" part of the [status bar](http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#status-bar) where you see the coordinates and zoom level.

I don't know a way to do the "enter long/lat in degrees but display in UTM" though.

Comment: This feature works but you need to have a non-metric lat/lon supporting coordinate system like WGS84. When cooordinates are entered be aware that QGIS expects the format "lon lat" make sure that subdecimals need to be separated by a "." only and lon and lat coordinates need to beseparated by a blank, even though they are displayed differently
E.g. For Madrid "-3.68594 40.39203" needs to be entered although "-3,68594°  40,39203°" will be displayed later on (clearly a usability bug to me)

Answer (score 25):

I found out a pretty nice plugin which perfectly suited my needs about dealing back and forth between a local SCR and Lat/Long data with various web tools, so I thought I may share..

It's called [Lat Lon Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/) and it's an open source project developped by the NSA.

This tool is able to zoom easily to Lat/Long coordinates copy pasted from your clipboard or open directly a point from QGIS to a map in your web browser.

[image: Lat Long tools menu screenshot]